# How to use Citrix XenApp for HomeUse on Windows 7?

Tags: ipad, citrix, xenapp

I have downloaded the Citrix Receiver from the AppStore on my iPad and i have enjoyed the DemoCloud, so i want to use it but just for homeuse and using my Windows 7 Ultimate x64 operating system.

Any help is welcome !
Regards,
Peyman Mortazavi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citrix XenApp is neither intended nor suitable for home use. It requires a Windows Server OS and will not run on Windows 7.

I agree that it is a cool way to get a Windows desktop to an iPad, but XenApp does not bring *your* Windows 7 desktop to the iPad but a standardized enterprise desktop.

I recommend you take a look at remoting products for PCs like [Remote PC](http://blog.idrive.com/?p=602).